# FInd furthest point in O(1) time

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

Consider a set S of n points in the plane such that the farthest pair is having distance at most 1. I would like to find the farthest point of a given query point q (not in S) in O(1) time. How do I pre-process the points in S to achieve the desired query time bound?

Can this be possible?

Comment: Do you mean the points are stored in a "set" type data structure? Because I'm pretty sure that's going to be 'no.'

Comment: Just wondering, is `q` in `S`? If not, my answer below is not suitable.

Comment: How I read it, `q` is taken from `E^2`. That being said, if the set of query points is unrestricted, O(1) lookup is impossible.

Comment: Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bsp_tree

Comment: I'm not really sure why would you need this. You are asking to pre-process result when you are getting dynamic input, which I think is not really possible. I would suggest you look `Convex Hull`. That might solve your situation.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible stricto sensu. This is a point location problem in a planar straight line graph, which is known to require O(log(N)) query time.

Anyway, it can be addressed approximately by gridding.

Overlay a square grid over the furthest point Voronoi diagram, and for every cell note the regions it covers. Make sure that the number of covered regions is bounded. This can be approximately achieved by taking a grid pitch smaller than the distance of the two closest vertices in the diagram.

For a query pixel, finding the containing cell is done in constant time. Then finding the region among a bounded number takes constant time as well.

Comment: +1, but I'm guessing that the O(log n) lower bound is for general straight line graphs -- isn't it possible that all furthest-point Voronoi diagrams are special kinds of straight line graphs, for which some faster algorithm might exist?  (I think a definitive "no" answer would need to show that *every* straight line graph is the furthest-point Voronoi diagram of some point set...  I have no intuition about these diagrams, but my first thought is that this seems unlikely.)

Comment: @j_random_hacker: the farthest point Voronoi diagram has only H region (number of points on the convex hull), leading to query complexity O(log(H)), which may be better than O(log(N)). On the other hand, I guess that the 2H degrees of freedom of the convex hull are preserved by the diagram and I don't believe that sub-logarithmic complexity is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is no relation between the points, there is no single operation that will give you the furthest point. So, the only way to do it is to compute it in advance, so you need a simple mapping between each point and the point furthest from it.

Comment: "so you need a simple mapping between each point and the point furthest from it." - the set of query points is unrestricted. How do you suggest to store the mapping?

Comment: Just stumbled over the same question, whether `q` is in `S` (making it restricted) or not.